# Question being closed as answer is written

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions

I'm aware of this [topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310144/questions-being-closed-as-answers-are-being-written), but my question is about deleted posts not closed posts...

---

#### An example:

Earlier today, I was reviewing a code project on Code Review. It took about one and a half hour for me to list the problems the code had and write another shorter version.

However, when I finally had finished debugging the code, I went back to the editor only to see that the question had been **deleted** (not closed) by the original poster. I was annoyed, to say the least.

I tried to contact the original poster via one of his other thread on Stack Overflow. He hasn't responded yet. Fortunately, I have managed to keep the question and original code so if I really need to I could just publish another thread making the question my own.

This can't happen! We're encouraged to write detailed answers not only showing the solution but also explaining it to the original poster.

---

#### Proposal:

I know that when a question gets published the poster can delete his post as long as he hasn't received any answers:
[image]

If the user wishes to **delete** his question and another user is in the process of answering it I believe there should be a message prompted like:

[image]

---

#### Question:

What do you think? Is it even possible to determine if someone is in the process of answering it (i.e writing in the editor to answer the question)?

---

PS: I didn't know there was such thing as ["undelete votes"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions). But it's unrelated to this topic, I'm talking about **the question maker deleting his question on his own**.

Comment: How are we going to detect *answering is in progress*?

Comment: well, there's ways to do so, but for an entire hour? how do we know you didn't just leave for the weekend with a window open.

Comment: Related: [Do not delete questions that have recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277553/21960)

Comment: I don't think this is related. It's not about others deleting the post but about the original poster deleting his own post.

Comment: We should not force people to not delete their question just because someone might be writing answer. If you're concerned about those things, don't answer new questions and you won't have that risk.

Comment: It's not forcing anyone, I am simply suggesting to put a message to inform the user that someone else is writing an answer for him. "don't answer new questions and you won't have that risk" really?

Answer (score -3):

Before answering I would suggest you upvote the question. 
If it's already been downvoted write a comment explaining why you think the question is good and plan to answer it.

I'm sure you aware that StackExchange network is very brutal and quick in downvoting questions. Even coherent and clear questions with interesting and probably simple to implement ideas like your own.

One person doesn't think your idea is practical and even that it has no relation to the quality or importance of the discussion he will downvote your question. Then the wave of reviewers will quickly follow downvoting
the topic even more. I won't be surprised if that's what happened before the original poster deleted his post.

Upvoting might help the original question to not be carried by the automatic wave of useless downvotes.

I don't think prevent a user from deleting his own question is a desirable idea. But I do favour the idea of letting him know someone is trying to answer his question before he decides to delete it.

Don't be dithered by the lack of serious response from moderators on meta. I had much [smaller fixes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311308/review-process-should-have-better-explanation-and-termnology) that were completely rejected without being properly addressed. Keep offering good ideas and improvements like the ones you did hopefully eventually someone who cares will notice them.

Comment: 90% of this answer is just rant. You can leave only the first paragraph, and it will be a fair answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure I agree. The first part is the quick answer but the following paragraphs explain the reason behind it. I know some people put straight answers without explaining them but I  don't like this kind of answers. The last paragraph is not on the point but it helps the author who asked a  good question and suggested a few reasonable ideas to know that downvoting his question and not getting proper response from the network is not his blame but an overall issue. But after reading it I understand it is not exactly convening the right spirit so I'll edit it to fix it